# controling network communication

Tags: android, communication, packets

I need to develop an Android application that sets up connection via WiFi with computer and then sends packets with data. Jowever, I need to control send packets, not only theirs data but also headers, there should be possible to modify any field in their header as well. In windows in it is possible with use of winpcap and jpcap, and I wonder if sth similar I may find on Android. Is there any ready API that will help with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's no API available to a Java/Dalvik app on Android which would allow you to do that.

Android is a Linux system, though. So you could try to find/write one or two Linux applications to support your effort - or use JNI.

Bottomline: Native code will definitely be necessary to achieve what you want, no way to do this in Java alone.

Comment: Ok that's probably what I need to do any furhter more detail tips? Is this the way which I should follow: http://blog.umitproject.org/2011/05/libpcap-for-android.html ?